# How to resolve the Invalid Column Index Exception?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the String value from Name column present in Table Books. But every time i am getting Invalid Column Index Exception in Oracle.

```
String name111=null;
String isbn=issuecall.getText();
String s1="Select Name from Books where ISBN='"+isbn+"'";

try{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","nitinrawal11");
    st1=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery(s1);
    while(rs.next()){
        name111=rs.getString(2);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

getname.setText(name111);

Comment: Your query only returns one column, not two, so you can't call `rs.getString(2)` .

Comment: Beside that, you should look into [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have written native sql as

> String s1="Select Name from Books where ISBN='"+isbn+"'";

It will return only one column however you are trying to get value at 2nd column

> name111=rs.getString(2);

You need to use **name111=rs.getString("name"); or name111=rs.getString(1);**

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only a single column. Read the doc to understand it better

> ```
> String getString(int columnIndex) throws SQLException;
> ```
>
> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
>
> @param columnIndex **the first column is 1, the second is 2**, ...
>   @return
>   the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is
>   null.

---

So use

```
rs.getString(1);
```

OR

```
rs.getString("Name");
```